# Почему в функциях класса можно обращаться к полям др класса, а в самом классе нельзя?

Tags: c++

```
class a
{
 public: 
    int b=0;
};

class c
{
 public:
    a d;
    void print(a bb) {
        cout << bb.b;// здесь к полю можно
    }

    d.b=10;  // здесь к полю нельзя?
};
```

Почему в функциях класса можно обращаться к полям др класса, а в самом классе нельзя? В мейне тоже нормально все обращается, почему тогда в другом классе нельзя?

Comment: А что вообще значит присвоение "в самом классе", вне функции?! Если вы покажете `int b=0;` выше, то это *инициализация*, а не *присваивание*...

Comment: внутри объявления структур код программы вставлять нельзя. можно только объявления функции, и то желательно только предварительно.

Comment: `a d = { 10 };` - если класс a имеет подходящий конструктор.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь проблема не в обращении к полю, а в том, что это грамматически неверная конструкция: в определении класса ожидается набор объявлений, а вы предоставляете assignment выражение. Если же обратиться к полю внутри объявления, то всё ок:

```cpp
struct A {
  int a;
};

struct B {
  int b = (b, A{}.a);
};
```